# Springboot+MySQL table return empty

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm a new to java and trying to connect mysql database using springboot. But the data returned from the database.table is empty. Below is my code, where is the problem? There is no error code, which means that there is indeed a connection to the database.table. And my database does have data. I have read several similar questions, but none of them can solve my doubts.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&characterEncoding=utf-8
    username: root
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        naming:
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        format_sql: true
server:
  port: 8181
```

**Book.java**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="isbn")
    private String ISBN;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String Name;
    
    @Column(name="author")
    private String Author;
    
    @Column(name="introduction")
    private String Introduction;
}
```

**BookRepository.java**

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.demo.model.Book;

public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer> {

}
```

**BookController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Book;
import com.example.demo.dao.BookRepository;

import jakarta.annotation.Resource;

@RestController
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("ok");
        return "TEST";
    }
    
    @Resource
    private BookRepository bookrepository;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allbook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getAll() {
        
        List<Book> books = (List<Book>) bookrepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("data size : "+books.size());
        
        return (List<Book>) bookrepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

On the webpage it looks like this...
http://localhost:8181/allbook

```
[{},{},{},{}]
```

And the console on my eclipse is output like this...

```
data size : 4
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.isbn,
        b1_0.author,
        b1_0.introduction,
        b1_0.name 
    from
        book b1_0
```

Comment: This is my database.table https://imgur.com/cI6f8yy.png

Comment: if its printing data size : 4 then you know that its close to be being right.  what exactly are you expecting to see? do you see the data returned in the network call of your browser console?

Comment: I want to see the data in the table, just like the result of entering "SELECT * FROM library.book;" in mysql workbench. May I ask where is my code wrong?

Comment: It's a classic case of getter setters having issues. The reason might be lombok

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.  (Not png, but text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make fields camelcase format and it works as getter/setters are not matching which are generated by Lombok.

```
private String isbn;
private String name:
private String author;
private String introduction;
```

Comment: I changed it to lowercase, but the result is still empty.

Comment: Which IDE do you use, we need to ensure that it has the support enabled for lombok?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Comment: eclipse.  I have added dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: Still the same. I have installed lombok and made sure there is an entry for lombok.jar in eclipse.ini. After restarting eclipse and executing the project, it is still empty.

Comment: I found out why. I need to add @Data in book.java. I always thought that as long as there is **@Getter, @Setter**, it will be fine.

Comment: The previously added **@Data** is still empty, it should be because lombok is installed, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: But I don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote

Comment: It's okay, np, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your repository is wrong. Change this:

```
CrudRepository<Book, Integer>
```

like this:

```
CrudRepository<Book, String>
```

The second type must match the type of the ID field.

Also add a no-args constructor to the entity class. This is needed for Hibernate to map data from the query results.

Comment: I've fixed it and it's still empty.

Comment: I found out why. I need to add **@Data** in book.java. I always thought that as long as there is **@Getter, @Setter**, it will be fine.

Comment: The no-args constructor was missing.